# ¿Como recorrer un arreglo con diferente longitudes o tamaños en jQuery?

Tags: jquery, ajax

En una `petición Ajax` estoy recibiendo 3 parametros:

```
$.get('home/getgroups', function(data){     
        var res = $.parseJSON(data);
        var getArray ={
            'groups': res.groups,
            'make':res.make,
            'total':res.total
        }
```

Cada `parámetro` que estoy ingresando en la variable **getArray** es un arreglo con tamaños diferentes:
[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

> ¿Como podria recorrer los arreglos para que se vean ordenados?,
>   teniendo encuenta que cada arreglo dependende uno del otro, es decir:

```
    groupId "1" groupDescripction "Personal" realizadas "4" total "5"

    groupId "2" groupDescripction "Colegio" realizadas "1" total "1"

    groupId "3" groupDescripction "grupoNuevo" realizadas "1" total "1"

    groupId "4" groupDescripction "OtroGrupo" realizadas "0" total "0"
ETC
```

**CODIGO JQUERY**

```
for (var i = 0; i < Object.keys(getArray.groups).length; i++){

            $('.rowCard').append(`<div class="col-lg-3 col-md-6 col-sm-6">
                                <div class="card card-stats">
                                    <div class="card-header" data-background-color="${getArray.groups[i].groupColor}">
                                        <i class="material-icons">${getArray.groups[i].groupIcon}</i>
                                    </div>
                                    <div class="card-content">
                                        <p class="category">${getArray.groups[i].groupDateRegister}</p>
                                        <h3 class="title">${getArray.groups[i].groupDescription}</h3>
                                    </div>
                                    <div class="card-footer">
                                        <div class="stats">
                                            <i class="material-icons text-success">done_all</i>
                                            <a href="#pablo" style="color: gray;">Tareas Realizadas:${getArray.make[i]} / ${getArray.total[i]}</a>
                                        </div>
                                    </div>
                                </div>
                            </div>`);
                }
        });
```

Comment: Si el orden de los arrays te consta que es consistente con el primer array, entonces el código que pones debiera funcionarte. ¿Qué estás obteniendo ahora? ¿Tu problema es que muestra `undefined` en vez de 0?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Si tienes 3 arreglos, de los cuales el primero contiene todos los elementos de una lista, y los otros dos un atributo adicional para los N primeros elementos de esa lista, bastaría con hacer

```
var grouplength=getArray.groups.length;
for (var i = 0; i < grouplength; i++) {
  var group = getArray.groups[i];
  group.total = getArray.total[i] || 0;
  group.realizadas = getArray.make[i] || 0;

  $('.rowCard').append(`
  <div class="col-lg-3 col-md-6 col-sm-6">
    <div class="card card-stats">
        <div class="card-header" data-background-color="${group.groupColor}">
            <i class="material-icons">${group.groupIcon}</i>
        </div>
        <div class="card-content">
            <p class="category">${group.groupDateRegister}</p>
            <h3 class="title">${group.groupDescription}</h3>
        </div>
        <div class="card-footer">
            <div class="stats">
                <i class="material-icons text-success">done_all</i>
                <a href="#pablo" style="color: gray;">
                    Tareas Realizadas:${group.realizadas} / ${group.total}
                </a>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>`);
  }
});
```

Sin embargo me surge la pregunta: qué pasa si un dato de `total` o de `make` pertenece a otro grupo? En realidad cada array debiese tener un atributo `groupId` que permitiera hacer la relación. Y más aún, esos datos debieran venir relacionados desde el backend.